# FCM legacy API call responded with JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement the legacy call to FCM server where the response is unexpected. There it shows the Parsing Error which is not traceable for me as of now. I am posting the code snippet below. Please help me out if anything is missing or coded in wrong manner.

```
var request = require('request');

let message = {
"to": atoken,
"data": {
  title: "My first push notification",
  body: "Hello World!!!"
  }
  };

  // //let message = req.body.message;
  let key = "AIzaSyA1zIxVFJ3F7-_-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  request({
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
  headers: {
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'key=' + key
  },
  postData: JSON.stringify(message)
  },
  function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) {
    console.error('upload failed:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: true, data: { message: error.message } });
  } else {
    let data = response;
    console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', 
    data.toJSON());
    //res.status(200).json(response);
   }
  });
```

The response coming is:

```
 body:
 'JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0.\n',
 headers:
 { 'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
  date: 'Tue, 16 Apr 2019 06:34:05 GMT',
  expires: 'Tue, 16 Apr 2019 06:34:05 GMT',
  'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  server: 'GSE',
  'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39"',
  'accept-ranges': 'none',
  vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
  connection: 'close' },
  request:
  { uri:
   Url {
   protocol: 'https:',
    slashes: true,
    auth: null,
    host: 'fcm.googleapis.com',
    port: 443,
    hostname: 'fcm.googleapis.com',
    hash: null,
    search: null,
    query: null,
    pathname: '/fcm/send',
    path: '/fcm/send',
    href: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' },
   method: 'POST',
   headers:
   { 'Content-type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'key=AIzaSyA1zIxVFJ3F7-_-hrIbTHTehNRmTUwG8Z0',
    'content-length': 0 } } }
```

Comment: Which HTTP request library are you using? And also could you try removing Content-type?

Comment: Its npm module of request that i am using.

Comment: You may want to remove your authorization key from Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `postData: JSON.stringify(message)` in request.post() to `body: JSON.stringify(message)`.